# Does typescript have a standard type which is the empty interface?

Tags: typescript

Does typescript have a standard type which is the empty interface? As opposed to `any`, the type should result in type errors whenever you try to do anything with it - except cast it to a real type/any.

I know you can define it trivially, I just wondered if its already defined by the language.

`interface untyped {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty type in TypeScript is called `{}`

There are no built-in aliases for it.